# Springboot Initializer project for SpringBoot version 2.0.5.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring-boot

I wanted to create a Springboot project via https://start.spring.io/.
But there is no option for version 2.0.5.RELEASE, which my deployed projects are using.
Is there a link in spring website that I may have missed?


Thanks

Comment: why not create `2.1.5 (SNAPSHOT)` and change version in gradle

Comment: @Deadpool, I'm so sorry but my boss Wolverine has setup our project with 2.0.5.RELEASE :D!